# pgfplots bar chart xticks not align with bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Looks like xticks not align bars exactly, the first one AAA is missing:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
key,value
AAA,14.9
BBB,16.5
CCC,19.1
DDD,20.2
EEE,22.7
FFF,23.1
GGG,26.3
HHH,26.4
III,27.1
JJJ,30.8
KKK,35.5
LLL,37.3
MMM,110.0
}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xmin = 0,xmax=14,
    %ytick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\mydata}{key},
    xlabel = {category},
    ylabel = {weight},
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
    axis lines=left,
    bar width=30,
    height=14cm
]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=value] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Foremost, your plot misses the key `xtick=data`. Then the xtick labels and the data match.
- You probably don't want the first bar printed only half next to the y-axis. Replace `xmin = 0,xmax=14` by `xmin = -1,xmax=13`.
- Maybe you don't want the y-axis to start at the smallest value, the one of `AAA`. In this case add `ymin=0`.
- To shift the label of the x-axis down, use `xlabel style = {yshift=-5mm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
key,value
AAA,14.9
BBB,16.5
CCC,19.1
DDD,20.2
EEE,22.7
FFF,23.1
GGG,26.3
HHH,26.4
III,27.1
JJJ,30.8
KKK,35.5
LLL,37.3
MMM,110.0
}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xmin = -1,xmax=13,
    ymin = 0,
    %ytick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\mydata}{key},
    xtick=data,
    xlabel = {category},
    xlabel style = {yshift=-5mm},
    ylabel = {weight},
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
    axis lines=left,
    bar width=30,
    height=14cm
]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex,y=value] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, how to make sure the bar not overlap each other? something like 0.9 to keep bar width 0.9 and 0.1 as gap between bars.

Comment: @lucky1928 Change the bar width from 30 to 27 or 26. To find out whether there is a way to let the bar width adjust automatically, depending on the plot width and the number of data points, ask another question in the forum, as it is beyond my skills.